# Route around "special" network device

Tags: networking, iptables

I have a "security" modem, which redirects my external IP to its configuration page when accessed internally. In the following diagram:

```
  10.0.0.1 +-------+ 1.2.3.4
     +-----+ Modem |<---------+Internet
     |     +-------+
     |
     |
     |     +--------+ 192.168.1.1
     +---->| Router +------+
10.0.0.253 +--------+      |
                           |
           +--------+      |
           | Server |<-----+
           +--------+ 192.168.1.3
```

I have DMZ configured on the modem to `10.0.0.253` (the router), and DMZ on the router to `192.168.1.3` (the server).

```
nathan@InternetDevice $ curl 1.2.3.4
Hello from Server!

nathan@Server $ curl 1.2.3.4
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
blah blah router config page
...
```

I'd like to configure the router to automatically reroute any TCP, UDP, or ICMP connections from `192.168.1.x` to `1.2.3.4` to `192.168.1.3` instead, transparently. If there's a better way to achieve this (other than getting a less "special" modem), I'd accept that too.

The modem is essentially a black box, but both the router and server run Linux. Currently, I have a hostname which globally resolves to `1.2.3.4`, but the router's DNS server resolves to `192.168.1.3`. However, this fails with e.g. Chrome OS devices, which always use Google's DNS, and feels weird.

Comment: What you want is called NAT loopback/hairpinning/reflection. But you should probably try getting rid of the double NAT because it sucks. :D

Comment: Your modem is the gateway to your router on the 10.0.0.0/24 network. Your router is the gateway to your server on the 192.168.1.0/24 network. In order for your server to communicate outwards, it must use its gateway, the router. For the router to communicate out, it must use its gateway, the modem. This is the way routing works and there isn't a way to route around your gateway. You can get a bridged modem instead (though you might be able to put that existing modem into bridged mode if you had the credentials).

Comment: You should also to talk to your ISP about any specific configurations needed when replacing a modem or changing the modem mode.

Comment: @DanielB Double NAT is because modem doesn't support essentially any useful configuration; unfortunately, there's a two-year contract on keeping it plugged into the wall. Completely agree that it sucks.

Comment: As long as it supports setting a static route, you can use full routing on your “real” router.

Comment: @MaQleod The problem isn't that I want to avoid the modem for all connections, just those to `1.2.3.4`. And I've tried contacting the ISP. The official response is that the equipment is not meant to be configured past the existing settings, which include setting a daily reboot at a configured time.

Comment: @DanielB How would I do that?

Comment: To use static routes, you still need another gateway you can assign the route to, which means, from your router (or server - depending on where you put the route), you'd need access to another gateway to direct traffic for one or more IPs to in place of the existing gateway. Unless there is another gateway accessible from the router (or server), I don't see how a static route is going to help in this situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a script...

```
PUBLIC_IP="$(curl ipinfo.io/ip 2>/dev/null)";
DMZ_IP="192.168.1.3";

add_rule() {
        iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING --dst "${PUBLIC_IP}" --protocol "${1}" --match "${1}" --jump DNAT --to-destination "${DMZ_IP}";
};

add_rule tcp;
add_rule udp;

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE;
```